# Is there something like non-catchable exception in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, error-handling

**I would like to terminate application when error occurs, something similar to throwing an exception that cannot be caught.**

When C++ exception is thrown and not catched, Visual Studio 2017 automatically opens the file where exception is thrown and points to the exact line of exception in a text editor, which is exactly what I want, except that I would also like to prevent exception from being caught.

I tried using `abort(0)` and `std::terminate()`, but then a message box is shown, instead of pointing to the line in text editor where application is terminated.
Simillary, `exit(0)` only displays message to debugger output which says that application has exited.

**Is there a way to terminate application, but still make Visual Studio point to the line in text editor where application is terminated?**

Comment: Why don't you just throw an exception which is not caught by the application?

Comment: There are no exceptions that can't be caught by `catch(...)`.

Comment: Have you tried `assert`?

Comment: `std::terminate` should cause the Visual Studio debugger to bring up a Abort/Retry/Ignore window. If you hit Retry it will bring you to the point where `std::terminate` was called. With Visual Studio you can use [`__debugbreak()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f408b4et.aspx) to force a break point, but it won't actually terminate your application.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks, 'Retry' tip is useful.

Comment: I think the closest you could get is by throwing a lambda (`throw [] {};`) as you wouldn't be able to name the type to catch, but that can still be caught with `catch (...)`

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/

Comment: @BJovke I am trying to write a library. Some functions acquire resources and release them just before the fuction returns. If I throw exception in the middle of the function, and someone catches that exception, that would result in memory leak.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux And where do you see `catch(...)` in the question text? Or a mention of it? Even if there was one, in every `catch(...)` in a program there should be **always** some way of logging and/or notifying what went wrong. It shouldn't just silently eat the exception.

Comment: @krsi Why do you think that throwing an exception will result in a memory leak? If it really does then your code is flawed.

Comment: @BJovke If my function calls, for example GetDC() function of Windows API, and throws exception before calling ReleaseDC(), wouldn't it result in a memory leak? Similar case is with many DirectX functions where buffer or some other resource needs to be released after it is used.

Comment: I find `exit(0)` to be effective.  Unless you have atexit handlers which are mucking things up.

Comment: @krsi No it won't result in a memory leak unless if you wrote the code pretending that exceptions don't exist.

Comment: @krsi - doing that would be a flaw in your program logic.  `GetDC()` allocates a resource, so your program logic needs to ensure that it is released (using `ReleaseDC()`) when an exception is thrown.

Comment: @BJovke The question asks *"Is there something like non-catchable exception in C++?"*. The existence of `catch(...)` implies that there is no uncatchable exception. That's not exactly what the question is asking, and the question itself can be taken to imply that this fact is known, but it is related to the question.